# Adding different links to a blade template based on the guard

Tags: laravel

I have set up custom guards for my app using the laravel Auth.
I already have a custom `404.blade.php` in `resources\views\errors`.

`Auth::guard('admin')->User()`  with home route as abc.com/admin

and

`Auth::guard('portal')->User()`  with home route as abc.com/portal

I'm trying to set up 404 pages for them, or at least create a single 404 page with a link to 'home' which should take them to their homepage.
I'm currently on laravel 5.4

Comment: What do you mean by a 404 login page?

Comment: Sorry, just 404 pages. I took away the 'login'.

Comment: Shouldn't the second guard be portal and not admin?

Comment: yes please, i just corrected it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a single blade file for your 404 and put this code in it to redirect to your multiple home pages based on the guard:

```
@if(Auth::guard("admin")->check())

   <a href="abc.com/admin">home</a>
@elseif(Auth::guard('portal')->check())

   <a href="abc.com/portal">home</a>

@endif
```